# How to make a Stack Panel Visible based on the Tapped Event of a ListView in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, listview, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In my application, I am having a ListView. ListView lists a set of images.

So when the application is running, and when that page is loaded, a list of images are shown.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding imageLists}" Background="Red" Tapped="ListView_Tapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Green">
                    <Image Source="{Binding imagePath}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

                    <StackPanel Name="imageTitle" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Blue" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock  Foreground="White" Text="Dumy Image Title" FontSize="10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As you can see from the code, I have one image & stackpanel inside the listview. And the stackpanel's visibility has been set to collapsed for convenience.

The **StackPanel** `imageTitle` resides inside the ListView. Stackpanel contains a TextBlock housing the images name. For now it's dumy text.

On Tapping any image in the list, I am trying to make the stackPanel visible.

**The Code Behind:**

```
 private void ListView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          imageTitle.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Since the stackpanel is inside the listview & I am trying to make it visible on the tap event of the listview, I am not able to acheive the needed result. I know my code is wrong.

If I specify the stackpanel outside the listview, I can make it visible using the code I gave inside the ListView_Tapped function. But even in that case, I need to show the stackpanel (name of the image I clicked) inside the listview item (image I clicked).

Any help??

**Can this be achieved using only XAML?**

Comment: By tapping an image, you want to only make its corresponding title visible, or all titles in the list visible?

Comment: Yes. I want to make only it's title visible. All images are visible. Only titles are hidden. When I click on an image, it's title should be shown above the image, for rest of the images title is hidden. @Justin XL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pure xaml way.

Rather than changing the `Visibility` of the `imageTitle` (not a great UX), let's change its `Opacity` to make its appearing more interesting.

First we need to create a storyboard inside this data template. This storyboard will fade in the `imageTitle` in 400ms.

And then we drag a `ControlStoryboard` behavior from Expression Blend's Asset panel onto the top level `Grid`. Basically we want the storyboard to fire off when this `Grid` is tapped.

Please see below code for reference.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate">
    <Grid Background="Green">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="ShowImageTitleStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageTitle"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowImageTitleStoryboard}"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="imageTitle" Background="Blue" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0">
            <TextBlock  Foreground="White" Text="Dumy Image Title" FontSize="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: OK. Thank you. Let me try this solution. @Justin XL

Comment: Do a refresh, I forgot to include the name of the sb in the behavior. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [JustinXL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27400231/2681948) it can also be done by using *ChangePropertyAction*. Also pure XAML:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
     <Grid Background="Green">
        <Image Source="{Binding imagePath}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>                            
              <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                 <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=imageTitle}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
              </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>

        <StackPanel Name="imageTitle" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Blue" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
             <TextBlock  Foreground="White" Text="Dumy Image Title" FontSize="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
     </Grid>                    
</DataTemplate>
```

It's just another way to change a property - JustinXL's answer will provide nice animation with opacity, which will look much better.

Comment: A valid answer by using another cool behavior - `ChangePropertyAction`.

Comment: @JustinXL To be honest, I would also use your solution in this case.

Comment: The type 'ic:EventTriggerBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. @Romasz

Comment: @WD In both answers you need to add Behaviours SDK to your project - right click on references (Solution explorer window) -> add reference -> Windows Phone8.1 -> Extensions -> Behaviours tick. Then in XAML at the beginning you add namespaces: `xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:ic="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"`.

Comment: I didn't try Justin's answer. Your's worked. Thank you. @Romasz

Comment: @WD And you should try it. Apart from that IMO it deserves this green tick more than mine.

Comment: OK. Green Tick goes to him. And you will get some up-votes from me. @Romasz

Answer (score 0):

I dunno why you specifically want to handle the scenario using XAML. For the Microsoft's recommended MVVM model you should bind a property to your element field and then you can write a converter for the same to return back "Visible" or "Collapse".